# How to style a Symfony form check/radio group

Tags: php, css, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have a Symfony form that has a check group and a radio group. I need to add different CSS styles for the check boxes and the radios.

Form looks like this

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
->add('checkgroup', 'choice', array('choices' => array('A', 'B'), 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true))
->add('radiogroup', 'choice', array('choices' => array('Yes', 'No'), 'expanded' => true))
->getForm();
```

Twig form elements go like this

```
{{form_widget(form.checkgroup)}}
{{form_widget(form.radiogroup)}}
```

In such a way how can I apply different CSS styles to individual elements in this groups?

Comment: Do you want to add a CSS class to each group (like adding `'attr' => ['class' => 'someClass']` to `options` array) or do you want to add a specific class to each element inside the checkbox list or radio list?

Comment: No, that is doable. But no idea how to apply styles to individual items in that group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css selectors to select each element individually and apply the desired css code to them: [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes are rendered by the checkbox_widget block. You need to override it.

one of the solutions is by using ...

- [Symfony Form Theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-theming)